# Reducer can't read action.type REDUX

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, reducers

I'm new to redux and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

accessTokenActions.js file

```js
import { getAccessToken } from '../../utils/spotifyAuth';
import * as types from '../consts/types';

export const fetchAccessTokenRequest = () => ({
  type: types.FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN,
});

export const fetchAccessTokenSuccess = (data) => ({
  type: types.FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SUCCESS,
  payload: {
    data,
  },
});

export const fetchAccessTokenError = (error) => ({
  type: types.FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN_ERROR,
  payload: {
    error,
  },
});

export const fetchAccessToken = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchAccessTokenRequest());
  try {
    const response = await getAccessToken();
    if (!response) {
      throw Error();
    }
    return dispatch(fetchAccessTokenSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (err) {
    return dispatch(fetchAccessTokenError(err.response.data));
  }
};
```

accessTokenReducer.js file

```js
import * as types from '../consts/types';

const initialState = {
  accessToken: null,
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
};

const accessTokenReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case types.FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        accessToken: action.payload.access_token,
      };
    case types.FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        accessToken: null,
        isLoading: false,
        error: action.payload.error,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default accessTokenReducer;
```

index.js file

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import accessTokenReducer from './accessTokenReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  accessToken: accessTokenReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

configureStore.js file

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

const configureStore = () => {
  const middlewares = [thunk];

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    ),
  );

  return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

const/types file

```js
export const FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN';
export const FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN_ERROR = 'FETCH_ACCESS_TOKEN_ERROR';
```

I also have a selectors file(which I think doesn't affect the code cause I don't call any functions from there)

I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined error in my switch statement at the reducer function, I'm currently studying the redux documentation but I can't figure out what's going on

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you print the `action` in your reducer, check what it is